# Why $\ker \, d = k^{-1} (\ker \,j)$?

Tags: spectral-sequences

Here is the part of the book (user's guide to spectral sequences) I am reading:

> [image]

I have the following questions about this part:

1- Why we are sure that $k$ has an inverse (the user used $k^{-1}$)?

2- if $d = j \circ k$ why $\ker d = k^{-1}(\ker j)$?

3- Why $k (\ker d) = k'(\ker d/ \operatorname{im} d)$?

4- Why $ k'(\ker d/ \operatorname{im} d)$ is considered as the whole image of $k'$?

Could anyone help me answer those questions please?

Comment: The exponent $-1$ is used to denote the inverse image. Note that $\ker(j \circ k) = (j \circ k)^{-1}(\{0\}) = k^{-1}(j^{-1}(\{0\})) = k^{-1}(\ker j)$

Comment: @azif00 so it is not necessarily has an inverse in our case here, am I correct?

Comment: @Secretly yes there isn't necessarily an inverse.
If A is a set then $k^{-1}(A)$ is defined as follows: $k^{-1}(A)=\{x\in dom(k)|k(x)=a,\,for\,some\,a\in A\}$, where by $dom(k)$ I denote the domain of $k$.
So $k^{-1}(A)$ is again a set rather than the inverse of the function $k$.

Comment: Got it, thanks. @Fotis how about the rest of my questions?

Comment: @Secretly regarding question 4, $k'$ is a map $E'\rightarrow D'$.
So we get $k'(E')=im(k').$
But $E'$ is defined as: $E'=kerd/imd$, so the desired equality follows

Comment: Question 3 should also follow directly by the way $k'$ is defined, since $k'(e+im(d)):= k(e)$

Comment: @Fotis I am trying to digest your answer to question 3 now.